# Visual Studio not recognizing BuildFire's SDK as a project, and when I set any file as the startup object errors occur

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, plugins, buildfire

I'm following the instructions via BuildFire to make my own custom plugins, but when I open the sdk folder with Visual Studio 19', it asks me to set a startup object; anything I pick throws an error "failure to launch debug adapter", as well as "attribute 'program' does not exist".  In the tutorials it says just to unzip the SDK, and open it with your IDE and to run the main index.html; not sure what I'm missing here.

I tried creating a blank Asp.Net Core Web Application with both an empty and an Angular build and importing all the content from the SDK but it only recognizes the default files created by Visual Studio.

The expected result it to open the default "hello world" view of the control and widget that is the generic from the SDK; instead it either A: doesn't run at all with the program doesn't exist error, or in the case of the Core Web > Angular it just loads the default Visual Studio code.

Comment: While I'm pretty sure you can get the project running on Visual Studio just fine. It may be beneficial to use the BuildFire CLI https://www.npmjs.com/package/buildfire-cli

Comment: I've already tried that, and the closest I've gotten to "success" was using 2 command prompts, one with npm start and one with buildfire run.. then it loads them into the browser window, but it doesn't display any of the actual plugin stuff when I select the plugin from the bottom left of the dashboard.